# what is a BIOs Programmer used for?

Tags: integrated-circuit, spi, pll

Never used a BIOs programmer before. Wondering what are they for.

For my current project, I need something to configure my PLL chip, which has an SPI interface.
[image]
I already have the evaluation board for my PLL chip but I need something to program it. I don't know if a universal BIOs programmer like a Oumij EZP2019  [example one](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07YQXJQ8T) would do the job. Does anyone has suggestions? how would one usually program such IC?

Thanks

Comment: One would program such ICs using an external microcontroller (like an Arduino). Your BIOS programmer won't be of much use here.

Comment: i see, then i guess the easiest way is to contact analog device just to separately order it's debugger, thanks

Comment: It's not clear why you think a "debugger" would work either unless it is specifically mentioned in documentation.  Is there an MCU on the evaluation board?  Likely what you want is an MCU project board (an "Arduino" of appropriate I/O voltage might do it) or else a PC-based SPI interface like an FT2232.

Comment: It's hard to answer when you didn't say what development board you have.  If it's a board from the chip manufacturer, they often provide a way to program their development boards it from a PC.  That minimizes the effort to evaluate the chip, thus increasing the chance that you will use it in your design.

Comment: @crj11, yes you are right. I have the HMC830 eval board (https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/analog-devices-inc/EVAL01-HMC830LP6GE/1127-2912-ND/5269219?utm_adgroup=xGeneral&utm_source=google&utm_medium=cpc&utm_campaign=Dynamic%20Search&utm_term=&utm_content=xGeneral&gclid=EAIaIQobChMI7OW_uZKE6wIVCI_ICh1afwLhEAAYASAAEgIzUvD_BwE) and there is a compatible USB interface to program it. However i can't find the part number for that interface board nor I find places to purchase it separately..... that is why I was looking for alternatives, any suggestions?

Comment: Google "121726-2 board price" without the quotes and you will find the programmer board.  It usually comes with the more expensive version of the kit, but it doesn't look like ADI sells it by itself.

Comment: @crj11, found it, thanks so much!